# Syntax error from adding IF function to Visualforce error

Tags: visualforce

I've isolated a syntax error down to one simple addition of an inline IF function.

If I comment out Block B and uncomment A, it compiles fine and renders as expected. If all I do is comment out Block A and uncomment Block B, Mavensmate won't let me compile and throws this error:

```
Result: [COMPILE FAILED]: (RevenueSchedule) Syntax error.  Missing ')'  (Line: 1, Column: -1)
```

**Block A:**

```
<apex:inputText id="revAmt" 
rendered="{!IF(isLocked == false,'true','false')}" 
value="{!sched.revenue}" 
styleClass="amountField" 
onchange="updateTotals('{!revSched.lineItem.id}');" />
```

**Block B:**

```
<apex:inputText id="revAmt" 
rendered="{!IF(isLocked == false,'true','false')}" 
value="{!IF(revSched.scheduleType == 'L',revSched.totalRevenue,sched.revenue)}" 
styleClass="amountField" 
onchange="updateTotals('{!revSched.lineItem.id}');" />
```

As you can see, they are identical besides the addition of the IF function to block B. That's the only reason I haven't definitively concluded that the syntax error lies elsewhere on the page. Can anyone see anything definitely wrong syntactically with anything in Block B, or any reason Block A would compile but not B?

Comment: as an aside, why are you not using `{!IF(NOT(isLocked),true,false)}`; also I use `=` in formulas in lieu of `==` as merge field formulas don;t follow apex rules

Comment: I'm the fourth out of four developers to work on this, most of this was existing code

Comment: many sympathies - is `RevenueSchedule` the name of the VF page?  Sometimes I end up successively commenting out portions of the page in order to look for the issue; if you think this is MavensMate and not the VF compiler, try compiling in Developer Console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with an output field, but not an input field. The value parameter cannot conditionally bind to two different fields.

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardController="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputText value="{!IF(FIND(Account.Name, 'a') >= 0, Account.Name, Account.AccountNumber)}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This does not compile, but change inputText to outputText and it will work.

To make this work, you will need to move that logic into your controller.

Set up a conditional getter and a conditional setter to set/get the value of either sched.revenue or revSched.totalRevenue depending on the logic you want.